# How can I test angularJS ran a jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jasmine

I have been trying to get my head around animations in AngularJS. Can anyone tell me why the following test fails and how to get it to pass? The height and width remain unchanged in the test although in the browser it works fine..

```
var app = angular.module('glqcAnimations', []);

app.animation(".mutate", function () {
    return {
        addClass: function (element, className) {
            element.animate({
                width: "500px",
                height: "500px"
            }, "fast");
        }
    };
});

describe("animation tests", function() {

  var $compile, scope, $rootScope, $animate;

  beforeEach(module('mock.animate'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$animate_, _$timeout_, _$document_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $animate = _$animate_;
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
  }))

  it("should change the width and height of an element", function() {
    var element = angular.element('<div style="height:100px;width:100px"></div>');
    $compile(element)(scope);
    expect(element.css("height")).toBe("100px"); // Pass
    expect(element.css("width")).toBe("100px"); // Pass

    $animate.addClass(element, "mutate");
    $rootScope.$digest();
    $animate.flushNext('addClass');
    $timeout.flush(1000);
    expect(element.css("height")).toBe("500px"); // Fail expected 100px to be 500px
    expect(element.css("width")).toBe("500px"); // Fail expected 100px to be 500px

  });
});
```